# styling custom imported vue component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to style a custom component like such:

```
<my-component class="someClass" />
...
<style>
  .someClass {
    //styles here
  }
</style>
```

I have thus far been unsuccessful, how can this be accomplished?

Comment: Could you write up an example in codepen or something similar? We'd love some more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, with a button wrapped in a component imported through out the application, I managed to get it working like this:

```
<my-component class="someClass">I'm a button wrapped in 'my-component'</my-component>

<style scoped>
.v-btn.someClass {
    color: blue;
}
</style>
```

**Edit:**
I just realized your question is not about Vuetify, so v-btn is probably  not the class you are gonna look for. Maybe just the following in your case:

```
<style scoped>
button.someClass {
    color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, so if I gather correctly there is no way to directly apply a class to a custom component, I would need to find out what the "inner" classes are?

Comment: I'm not able to test right now but as a wild guess, I'd say so.

Comment: @Michael  You can give any `class` to a custom component and you can see it in DOM rendered to the parent div of the component. However, you cannot override a css with that class if component is scoped